# Identify children's SF story from early '70s

Tags: story-identification

I think the story was a trilogy from the children's scholastic reader. Here are the things I *think* I remember about it.

First book 3 children brothers/sister exploring hillside and discover a cave entrance. They follow some type of path or stairs that go deep underground and discover some city of 'mole people'.

Other books, their father was some kind of scientist that was presumed dead? The children discover clues that their father was stuck in some alternate dimension?

There was also something about an "X"; it was some kind of symbolic clue.

Comment: Hello sdproto, welcome to [fantasy.se] and thank you for your question. If you remember any additional details, such as what the cover looked like, you can [edit] them in. [Here's a list of possible clues](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/19561) to help you jog your memory.

Comment: 2 boys and a girl looking for a missing father trapped in another dimension sounds like [*A Wrinkle in Time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time) but I don't remember a tunnel to mole people.

Comment: @DavidW: my first thought also.  But no mole people.

Comment: Also sounds like Tunnels by Roderick Gordon and Brian Williams, initially self-published with the title, "The Highland Mole".  But the timeframe is wrong...

Comment: Thanks everyone, posted this before bed, need time to look thru your comments and I'll update. It was too long ago to remember the cover. I was also thinking if I could look thru the Scholastic Readers from that time I might recognize it, but I don't know if those are available anywhere.

Comment: Ok, after looking at the Wikipedia link, A Wrinkle in Time rings some bells for me, I think this is likely one of the books. I seem to remember that the mole people story had the same children and I thought it preceded the other book. I don't think the mole people were the main part of the story, just part of it. I think one of the mole people helped them with some clue or something. I really believe that the children were the same, but I could be wrong. I know it was at the same time and I got the books from the Scholastic Reader book club list.

Comment: it sounds like the OP has mixed up two different books.

Comment: The other book with the three children going down stairs and finding a city of 'mole people' might be The Secret World of Og by Pierre Berton, which is entirely likely to have been a Scholastic Reader book.

Comment: Thanks @nebogipfel I'll take a look at that also. I will post back here when I've finished reviewing the books all of you have suggested.

Comment: Update, 2 of the books I remembered were A Wrinkle in Time, and A Wind in the Door. I'm still looking to figure out the mole people book and locate a copy of The Secret World of Og. That title doesn't ring a bell, but if I can find it I'll take a look. Thanks for the suggestions everyone.

Comment: I didn't see these last comments until now (I never remember to click the "see more comments" button)  Hope my answer helps anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're talking about three books, which I will attempt to identify.

**First book 3 children brothers/sister exploring hillside and discover a cave entrance. They follow some type of path or stairs that go deep underground and discover some city of 'mole people'.**

"Power of Three" by Diana Wynne Jones  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_Three_(novel), which features the relationship between two fantasy races (the Lyman and the Dorig) and humans (who the others refer to as Giants)

> Lymen live in villages inside huge, hollow mounds. They fear the Giants and are at war with the Dorig. They operate their
> magic/technology with Words. They are warlike and like hunting, but
> they usually will not kill unless they have to. A few have special
> attributes called Gifts which enable them to use a special magical
> skill (e.g. see the future). Their clothes are the colour of the Moor,
> so they can camouflage with the long grasses, shadows, and trees. They
> look like humans, but are a little smaller, thinner, and have
> almond-shaped eyes which are the same colour as a human's.**

> Dorig live in halls under water. They have airlocks and working pumps.
> They, too, fear the Giants and they are at war with the Lymen. The
> Dorig have only the barest minimum of knowledge about Words and do not
> seem to have Gifts, but can shapeshift. They are rather peaceful, but
> are not reluctant to kill. Their real clothes are soft, and made of
> fish-skins that are prepared to shift shape along with the Dorig that
> is wearing them. When Dorig come to the surface, they don a hard,
> scaly armour that covers them head to foot and also shifts shape along
> with them.

The second book is "A Wrinkle in Time" by  Madeleine L'Engle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time

**Other books, their father was some kind of scientist that was presumed dead? The children discover clues that their father was stuck in some alternate dimension?**

> One night, thirteen-year-old Meg Murry meets an eccentric new
> neighbor, Mrs Whatsit, who refers to something called a tesseract. She
> later finds out it is a scientific concept her father was working on
> before his mysterious disappearance. The following day, Meg, her child
> genius brother Charles, and fellow schoolmate Calvin visit Mrs
> Whatsit's home, where the equally strange Mrs Who and the unseen voice
> of Mrs Which promise to help Meg find and rescue her father.
>
> Mrs Whatsit, Mrs Who, and Mrs Which turn out to be supernatural beings
> who transport Meg, Charles Wallace, and Calvin O'Keefe through the
> universe by means of a tesseract, a fifth-dimensional phenomenon
> explained as folding the fabric of space and time; this form of travel
> is called tessering.

The third book may be the sequel to Wrinkle: "A Wind in the Door" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wind_in_the_Door

**There was also something about an "X"; it was some kind of symbolic clue.**

> The Echthroi are powerful, evil creatures whose desire is **to X** (i.e.
> extinguish, unname) creation.

All three books would have been available in the mid 1970s.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I mentioned in the previous comments that "A Wind in the Door" and "A Wrinkle in Time" were 2 of the books I remembered, but the mole people book you describe doesn't click for me. It could be that it's just been so long I've forgotten, but also 1976 is too late. In 1976 we'd moved to a different state and the book I remember was before that. I'd estimate around 1974 because that when my sister was born and my parents needed to keep us entertained. I'm also certain it was a Scholastic Reader book. If I can find the book you mentioned I'll see if anything sticks out. Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome.  Sorry I missed the later comments that you made about Wrinkle and Wind.